# How should I set the download name of a pdf with fpdf?

Tags: php, character-encoding, fpdf

I am trying to set a name for a pdf file I generated with FPDF. However for some reason the browser changes some characters.

I am sending this:

```
$pdfTitle = 'Overview: 2017/2018'
$pdf->Output( 'D', $pdfTitle, true );
```

Yet when I save my pdf it changes some characters and I and the download name becomes: 'Overview_ 2017_2018'.

I am using UTF-8 encoding on my php file.

FPDF-documentation: http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm

I have two questions:

- **How can I make sure the download name is the same as the one I set in my php file?**
- **What is the underlying issue that changes the name?**

PS: In the real project the string will come from a database, so I can only access the string programatically and not make direct changes to it.

Comment: some O.S's doesn't allow "/" and ":"  in file names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the special characters **`:`** and **`/`** in your filename in your code. Because of this `fpdf` is filtering your outputs filename.

For example:

```
Overview: 2017/2018
        ^     ^       are not supported as filename in Windows & some other OS.
```

**Tip:**

You may add `.pdf` in your name if file is not saving as pdf file.

Comment: Are there perhaps characters that are visually identical to `:` and `/`? Then i can replace those characters in my strings. However I am not sure if that is a good idea ( I feel like the special character argument is too strong to do this workaround, even with lookalikes ). Unfortunately I can't change the string I receive. The user will have to make changes to the title or I would have to take the approach where I replace characters. Does anyone have any good / bad experiences with either of these approaches?